# pass existing function as parameter to another function in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

Im new to swift and was trying to find way to pass function as a parameter to another. My code structure is like below

```
func createDictionaryFromParams(param1: [String:String], param2: String, param3: String) -> [String:String] {
   param1["name"] = "John"
   param1["university"] = param2
   return [:]
}
func toPassAsParam() -> [String:String] {
   //doStuff
   return [:]
}

public struct passFunction {
   let dict = createDictionaryFromParams(param1: toPassAsParam(), param2: "Texas", param3: "Florida")
}
```

When I execute above code in playground/in my application i get error as "cannot assign through subscript: param1 is a let constant"

Not sure where Im going wrong. Please guide me. Please refer screenshot of exact code in playground[image]

Comment: This seems really sketchy. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter values are `let`s by default (and can't be mutated). This is the cause of your error message - it has nothing to do with being the result of `toPassAsParam()`. You can get around this one of two ways, depending if you actually want to change `param1` *outside* of the function.

If you do want `param1` to mutate and keep its new value, declare it as an `inout [String:String]` (the `inout` keyword means it can be mutated from in the function).

If you just want to be able to change it inside the function, you can just say `var param1 = param1` in the first line of your function (copy it to a variable).

A little more on the subject line of your question: you aren't passing a function as a parameter. You're passing one function's *return value* as a parameter to another function. If you wanted to pass the actual *function* to `createDictionaryFromParams`, it would look something like:

```
// note the type of `function`
func createDictionaryFromParams(function: () -> [String:String], 
                                param2: String, 
                                param3: String) -> [String:String] {
    var param1 = function() // now that we passed `function` in, we can call it to get a [String:String]
    param1["name"] = "John"
    param1["university"] = param2
    return [:]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not related to passing a function as a parameter; the error you have gotten is raising when you try to change function parameter because the parameter is defined as `let` and to change its value you need to make them `var`

So Only you need to change your code to something like below code:

```
func createDictionaryFromParams(param1: [String:String], param2: String, param3: String) -> [String:String] {

//here is changing constant to variable section
    var param1 : [String : String] = param1
    param1["name"] = "John"
    param1["university"] = param2
    return [:]
}
func toPassAsParam() -> [String:String] {
    //doStuff
    return [:]
}

public struct passFunction {
    let dict = createDictionaryFromParams(param1: toPassAsParam(), param2: "Texas", param3: "Florida")
}
```